# How to find all documents with field values that start with a given string in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do a query in mongodo where I have get all documents that start have a type that starts with a value - eg ea

I have the following in my pipeline

```
$matchPipeline["TYPE"] = ['$in'=> ["EAVWF", "EA"]];
```

I would like to find all types that start with 'EA', so I don't have to type them out.

Comment: Do you have only capital case?

Comment: Yes I do. Case doesn't matter for this

Comment: Reason is that case insensitive regex may not use index properly?

Answer (score 3):

You may use regex

```
db.getCollection('collectionname').find({"TYPE": {"$regex": "^EA"} })
```

Startwith queries can potentially use indexes. So, It will perform good if you create index on TYPE.

By default $regex is case sensitive

Case Insensitive version. Would perform poorly on large data

```
db.getCollection('collectionname').find({"TYPE": {"$regex": "^EA","$options": 'i'} })
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a alook

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it answered your query

Comment: Heads up @Holy_diver, there's a " missing on "$options"

Comment: @CamK Thanks for the suggestion, i have corrected it.